# 8-input NAND Gate

Tags: vhdl

I am have an assignment to make an 8 Input NANDGate using a for loop.

This is what I have so far:

```
entity NANDGATE is 
    port ( 
        A: in  std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);  
        X: out std_logic
    );
end entity;

architecture behavioral of NANDGATE is
begin
    process (A)  
    begin
        op <= ’0′;   
        for i in 7 downto 0 loop 
            if inp(i) = ’0′ then  
                op <=’1′;
            end if;
        end loop;
    end process;
end architecture behavioral;
```

I just starting learning about VHDL I am not that good at it, I hope someone can help me so I can understand.

Comment: How it is related to the C++? Tag spamming will not give you more answers, but downvotes and more chance your question would be closed.

Comment: And you did not ask a question.

Comment: In your process you're using `op` instead of `x` as an assignment target and evaluate `inp` instead of `A`.  Note neither `op` nor `inp` are declared nor made visible. You're missing a context clause and your code also contains non ISO 8859-1 characters instead of apostrophes in character literals '1' and '0'. Your for loop if statement could have an exit statement to discontinue execution on finding the first '0' element of `A`. Do you have a specific question? The [tag:gate] tag wasn't appropriate either.

Comment: See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) "Questions asking for *homework* help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." You're not asking anything specific nor describing the difficulty you are encountering with your assignment.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using VHDL 2008, simply write:

op <= nand A;

No for loop needed.

Comment: Note the part about using a for loop in the assignment.